# SQL Query to retrieve messages from all user's friends

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have 3 databases setup for a Twitter-clone website.

Table 'users':

```
email | firstname | lastname | hash_password
```

Link Table 'friends':

```
email | friend
```

This lists all users and their friends.  Friendships are 1-way (like Twitter's "Following"/"Followers").
`friends` table is a link table to list all users' friends.  So both `friends.user` and `friends.friend` are foreign keys to `users.email`.

Table 'messages':

```
timestamp | user | content
```

What is an SQL query to retrieve all messages from a user and his friends?

---

I've tried:

```
SELECT
  'timestamp', 
  user, 
  content 
FROM
  messages
  INNER JOIN friends ON messages.user = friends.friend
ORDER BY 'timestamp' DESC;
```

This seems to join them correctly, but how can I only get the messages for a specific user's (email address) friends.  Right now this just returns all messages.

Thanks.

Comment: i cant see any column called user in messages and friends table

Comment: You need to add a where clause - something like where users.email='$email'

Comment: also you have not joined user table in your join anywhere

Comment: Yeah, apologies, my columns in the 'friends' link table are actually called "user" and "friend", but they hold the email only, so just called them "user_email" and "friend_email" here for clarity.

Comment: can you edit your question please

Comment: what is relation between user and friends table?

Comment: i meant how are you joining user and friends table? I think you need to join user table to your existing query and add where clause

Comment: See edit.  Thought we might need to join a third table, wasn't sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoting of `timestamp` should be with backticks, otherwise MySQL will assume a string literal value.

Otherwise, to return messages from both the user and all friends, you may use a `UNION`. One half returns the user's messages, the other half returns friends' messages. You need to add the user's email to your join condition:

```
/* First part of the UNION returns friends messages */
SELECT
  `timestamp`, 
  user, 
  content 
FROM
  messages 
  /* The join ON clause specifies the main user email */
  INNER JOIN friends 
    ON messages.user = friends.friend
       AND friends.email = 'email@example.com'
UNION ALL
/* Other part of the UNION just gets all messages for the main user by email addr */
SELECT
  `timestamp`,
  user,
  content
FROM
  messages
WHERE user = 'email@example.com'
/* ORDER BY applies to everything */
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC;
```

And if you want to join in the `users` info (`firstname/lastname`) here, the easiest way to go about it would be to wrap the entire thing in a subquery and join.

```
SELECT
  users.*,
  messages_sub.content,
  messages_sub.`timestamp`
FROM
  users
  JOIN (/* The entire thing from above */) AS messages_sub ON users.email = messages_sub.user
ORDER BY `timestamp`
```

It can also be done with a `UNION` of the literal email address you want to find and the friend list, producing only one outer query.  This is a little trickier, but may be ultimately faster. It will also be less confusing to bring in other columns from the `users` table here. I'll add the names:

```
SELECT
  `timestamp`,
  user,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  content
FROM
  messages
  INNER JOIN (
    /* Union query produces a list of email addrs - 
       the person you're looking for plus all his friends
       Starts with string literal for the main user
    */
    SELECT 'email@example.com' AS email
    UNION 
    /* Plus all his friends into one list joined against messages */
    SELECT friend AS email FROM friends WHERE email = 'email@example.com'
  ) user_and_friends ON messages.user = user_and_friends.email
  /* Join against the users table for name info */
  INNER JOIN users ON user_and_friends.email = users.email
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

Comment: dont you think we need to join user table as well?

Comment: @AshReva Yes, hang on. I missed part of the schema.

Comment: @AshReva Actually, no there needn't be a join against `users` unless more columns from that table are needed. The original question only asks for columns from the `messages` table.

Comment: seems to puzzled me. Not sure why user has given that user table when its not required. I thought we just needed to join 3 tables.

Comment: @AshReva If the OP wants firstname/lastname in the output it will be needed. Otherwise it isn't because `email` is the PK and FK in `friend`.

Comment: I did require it to return firstname and lastname so this is perfect, thanks very much.

P.S. Just FYI, couple of typos: "friend" should be "friends" on 5th last line and should be "user_and_friends.email" on 2nd last line.